# Flex slider on modal window doesn't work unless I click inspect element

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I am trying to develop a wordpress theme that has a modal window which displays a slide gallery of images queried from advanced custom field gallery. I am using FLEXSLIDER.

Here is my code below:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">                                  

      <?php 
        $images = get_sub_field('featured_projects');
        if( $images ): ?>
          <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
              <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <li>
                  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                  <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="custom-navigation">
              <a href="#" class="flex-prev">Prev</a>
              <div class="custom-controls-container"></div>
              <a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>                  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button to trigger the modal to show, the first image is displayed together with the image list but when I click the next or previous button, the slider doesn't move, but when I click the **inspect element** to see if the images are loaded, the next and previous buttons surprisingly works and shows the next images.

Here is the output when flex slider is loaded the first time:
[image: screenshot]

Here is the output when I open inspect element:
[image: screenshot2]

The query trigger for Flexslider:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlsContainer: $(".custom-controls-container"),
    customDirectionNav: $(".custom-navigation a"),
  });
});
```

Is there something I am missing? Another guy encountered same problem but did not get an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767003/flex-carousel-items-are-not-displaying-properly-until-i-clicked-on-inspect-eleme. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's worked for me.

```
    var initFlexSliders = function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "slide",
          slideshow: false,
          controlNav: false,
          directionNav: true, 
          start: function(slider){
              $('.flexslider').resize();
          }
      });
  };

//call this function to show the slider
initFlexSliders();
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still having this issue just try to add this line at the end of your page.that worked for me.

```
<script>jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();</script>
```